# I need help streaming an online radio http://www.vdee.org:8000/salinas . I have this code so far

Tags: swift, audio-streaming

I need to stream an online radio station to put into an ios app using swift. Mine is running but not playing.

```
var player:AVPlayer?
var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
var playButton:UIButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.vdee.org:8000/salinasMim")
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
    playerLayer.frame=CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:50)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    playButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system) as UIButton
    let xPostion:CGFloat = 50
    let yPostion:CGFloat = 100
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 150
    let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 45

    playButton!.frame = CGRect(x: xPostion, y: yPostion, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    playButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    playButton!.setTitle("Play", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    playButton!.tintColor = UIColor.black
    playButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.playButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(playButton!)
}

@objc func playButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    if player?.rate == 0
    {
        player!.play()
        //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_pause_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        playButton!.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    } else {
        player!.pause()
        //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_play_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        playButton!.setTitle("Play", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I check your code. it's working fine with below VOD content and it should also work with DTV content.

```
    https://cstr-vod.castr.io/vdafddac30977c11e9bdcb/71983cc5-f510-4b36-b77a-fc3d216e15d3/index.m3u8
    http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8
```

I am not able to get response from your URL: http://www.vdee.org:8000/salinasMim

Please use this URL:http://www.vdee.org:8000/salinas
this DTV content is working fine please check. You can listen the audio as the content in audio only.

Answer (score 0):

```
var player:AVPlayer?
var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
var playButton:UIButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //https://cstr-vod.castr.io/vdafddac30977c11e9bdcb/71983cc5-f510-4b36-b77a-fc3d216e15d3/index.m3u8
    //http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.vdee.org:8000/salinas")
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
    playerLayer.frame=CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:50)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    playButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system) as UIButton
    let xPostion:CGFloat = 50
    let yPostion:CGFloat = 100
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 150
    let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 45

    playButton!.frame = CGRect(x: xPostion, y: yPostion, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    playButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    playButton!.setTitle("Play", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    playButton!.tintColor = UIColor.black
    playButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.playButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(playButton!)
}

@objc func playButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    if player?.rate == 0
    {
        player!.play()
        //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_pause_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        playButton!.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    } else {
        player!.pause()
        //playButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "player_control_play_50px.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        playButton!.setTitle("Play", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
}
```